# Server Web Service Soap - WSDL - Java Eclipse

Tags: java, web-service, eclipse, soap, wsdl

Sei que já existe muito post relacionado a web service em java e também sei que já houve muitas perguntas com esse meu problema. Porem, tentei de todas as formas e não consegui resolver, por isso estou aqui.

Esse é meu log do servidor. O problema está aqui

```html
ago 21, 2017 11:39:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFORMAÇÕES: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
ago 21, 2017 11:39:24 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
ADVERTÊNCIA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:ProsegurWsServer' did not find a matching property.
ago 21, 2017 11:39:24 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
ago 21, 2017 11:39:24 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
ago 21, 2017 11:39:24 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMAÇÕES: Initialization processed in 995 ms
ago 21, 2017 11:39:24 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting service Catalina
ago 21, 2017 11:39:24 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
ago 21, 2017 11:39:26 AM org.apache.axis.configuration.EngineConfigurationFactoryServlet getServerEngineConfig
GRAVE: Unable to find config file.  Creating new servlet engine config file: /WEB-INF/server-config.wsdd
ago 21, 2017 11:39:26 AM org.apache.axis.utils.JavaUtils isAttachmentSupported
ADVERTÊNCIA: Unable to find required classes (javax.activation.DataHandler and javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart). Attachment support is disabled.
ago 21, 2017 11:39:26 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
ago 21, 2017 11:39:26 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
ago 21, 2017 11:39:26 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFORMAÇÕES: Server startup in 1819 ms
```

> GRAVE: Unable to find config file.  Creating new servlet engine config file: /WEB-INF/server-config.wsdd

Acredito que o grande motivo de não conseguir rodar direito meu servidor é esse erro, encontrei vários links com a solução, como: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289781/why-is-server-config-wsdd-not-being-created-by-the-eclipse-web-services-wizard e http://www.guj.com.br/t/web-service-axis/128071/3 mas não tive exito realizando todo o procedimento proposto. Alem disso, quando o server roda mesmo com os problemas e erros existentes o eclipse me retorna uma pagina de erro 404, como: http://www.guj.com.br/t/resolvido-erro-http-status-404-primeira-aplicacao-web/77469/6 Porem, tambem não consegui a solução.